# Create a LaTeX document for purely math, supporting \\ or \newline

Tags: math-mode, environments, overleaf, document-classes

I'm creating a LaTeX document in Overleaf purely as a cheat sheet and notepad for math I often use. Unfortunately, I don't know what sort of documentclass I would use, or if one even exists. I considered just using an article, and just enclosing everything in one big equation environment, but they don't support newlines.

Is there an environment or documentclass I could use for this?

Comment: There are lots of multiline maths environments that use ` \\\` to mean 'move to the next line'. However, it would be simpler to put each equation in its own environment. It's not much extra typing to do `\[ whatever \]`.

Comment: @user202729 --- Thanks. I can never remember the markup for all of the different systems I have to use these days!

Comment: @IanThompson Can you maybe tell me what these environments are?

Comment: Take a look at the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

Comment: I think `gather` is probably closest to your usage case.

Comment: amsmath and one large `gather`